# jquery hidden div remove field required

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms

How to remove required in hidden fields. It must remain required in visible field.When one of the options is selected, the required field needs to be removed. This form created django framework.

For example, when "tuzel" is selected, the required field needs to be removed from the adi field.

Jquery Code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){

                $(".col").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".col").hide();

            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>

<select name="secenek" class="form-control select2" required id="id_secenek">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="tuzel">Tüzel</option>

  <option value="gercek">Gerçek</option>
</select>

              <div class="tuzel col col-lg-6">
                <div  id="fnWrapper" class=" parsley-input">
                  <label class="form-control-label">Firma Ünvanı: <span class="tx-danger">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="firma_adi" class="form-control" id="id_firma_adi" maxlength="256" required/>
                </div>
              </div><!-- col-4 -->
              <div class="gercek col col-lg-6">
                <div  id="fnWrapper" class=" parsley-input">
                  <label class="form-control-label">Adı: <span class="tx-danger">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="adi" data-parsley-class-handler="#fnWrappe" class="form-control" required="True" id="id_adi" maxlength="128" required/>
                </div>
              </div><!-- col-4 -->
```

Comment: just remove the required attribute from the field. $('#id_adi')..removeAttr('required');
AND add attribute when 'tuzel' not selected.

Comment: I've tried this before. also remove when the field is visible(show)

Comment: check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nfc4yqds/7/.. I have created for you.

Comment: @AbdulRauf If there are more than one hidden fields, can we process only the fields we have specified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a fiddle using your code that how you can apply required on the filed.

See this: [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/nfc4yqds/7/)

You need to add two more lines in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            console.log(optionValue);
            if(optionValue){
                $(".col").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
                                $('input[type="text"]').removeAttr('required');
                                $("." + optionValue + " input").attr('required','true');
            } else{
                $(".col").hide();

            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(optionValue){
    $(".col").not("." + optionValue).hide();
    $(".col").not("." + optionValue).removeAttr('required');​​​​​
    $("." + optionValue).show();
    $("." + optionValue).attr('required', true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for participating in stackoverflow ccesare. :) While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.